# MS Access 2007: How to calculate a column form other columns in the same table in a query?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

In `Orders` table I have `Item Price` and `Item Count` fields. I need a query with an extra column: `Total Price` which as query is executed holds: `Item Price` * `Item Count`.

I have created one in query builder but when I open it, a dialog asks for `Total Price` parameter which should be calculated and showed automatically (I don't mean to pass it as a parameter to query). Maybe below query is not in correct syntax or there's a better way to do the job:

```
SELECT Orders.[Item Price], Orders.[Item Count], [Item Count]*[Item Price] AS [Total Price]
FROM Orders;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your syntax.  Is there already a column called "Total Price" from the table that you are pulling from?

Comment: Any chance you can upload your DB to a hosting site and post the link?